# Reading a txt file into a list in python

Tags: python

I just started to learn python and I was wondering how to read a bunch of numbers from a txt file and put it into a sort of list. The txt file I want to read has three numbers next to each other with a space in between.

Like this:

`24 39 45\n`

I want to read this file into a list:
`[24, 39, 45]`

How can I do that? The `.readlines()` method doesn't seem to work as it turns the whole line into one single element: `list[0] = ['24 39 45\n']`.

Pardon me if this sounds like a stupid question. This is my first question here. Thank you!

Comment: You can just use the str.split() method. split() takes the delimiter as its parameter, but splits on whitespace if none is given.

Answer (score 1):

```
.readLine().split()
```

It reads the full line, and uses split to separate it into space-separated values.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.read().splitlines()` to first get a list where each element looks like `['24 39 45']` then, a [`.map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with a [`.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split each of those by space.

```py
with open(filename, 'r') as textfile:
    content = textfile.read().splitlines()
content = list(map(lambda x: x.split(' '), content))
```

Output-

```py
[['24', '39', '45'], ['52', '42', '39']]
```

Where textfile was-

> 24 39 45
>
> 52 42 39

This will return a list of lists, where each element will be a list of numbers

Answer (score 0):

try the code follows

```
g = open("demofile.txt", 'r')
step1=g.readlines()
step2=[]
for a in step1:
    step2.append(a.split())
print(step2)
```